# self.view addSubview layer

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

When using

```
[self.view addSubview:foo];
```

is there a way to specify which layer the object will go to? i.e. is it possible to not have the object added go to the top of the view layer above all objects? I use addSubview to dynamically add view objects, but I would like for some of them to be NOT on the top of the stack, if you know what I mean. I can elaborate more if my explanation is not understandable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use one of those functions (all from UIView), depending on what you want to do

```
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
- exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

(behaviors are pretty obvious with the names).

Comment: Wow- can't believe I missed this; I should have looked at the UIView documentation first. Thank you!

Comment: No worries :-). Don't forget to validate the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: Haha I couldn't because you responded so soon after I posted it- you have to wait fifteen minutes or something before marking an answer- marked now!